# How to prevent unnecessary render when fetching static content?

Tags: reactjs

When I use react hooks I declare my state to be like this:

```
const [entities,setEntities] = useState([])
```

Then I make an api call to the server that return static content that never changes.
I `setEntities(fetchedData)` and what is actually happening is that I render the component twice - Once when the array is empty and the second time is when the data arrives. The data is static and it never changes. Was wondering if there is a certain way to prevent this unnecessary render? I thought the solution will be to make the api call on componentWillMount but there isn't any parallel solution with hooks to this, as this method is not used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to render that component **only once**, you could move the fetching logic to it's parent.

In parent:

```
fetchData();
entities; // where the data from request is stored
```

Then use a basic render condition:

```
{entities && <Child entities={entities} />}
```

Then, wrap  the Child component with `React.memo` to avoid re-renders if parent re-rendered.

```
export const Child = React.memo(() => {
  ...
});
```

Finally, what is most important - operate over props, do not save it inside state. So if you want to do something with the `entities`, use it as props.

```
{props.entities.map(...)}
```

The `Child` will render only once, when `entities` data is received from API. If only you won't call API anymore, it will stay at it is.

Comment: In that case you will get double render of parent. Because you have to store fetched data.

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy There's no way to avoid the second re-render when fetching data from async call. But there is a way to avoid re-render in component that uses it.

Comment: Well you avoid render smaller component and call render bigger. What if parent has more than one child? What if children are not memorized?

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Then memoize it? Excuse me, but I dont see the point of this discussion. Even if this is slightly complicated but doable, it's still better then your suggestion to do nothing because "you can't". This is how performance improvement looks like, you have to dig it. No one said it was easy. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

componentWillMount are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

And you cannot render data once.

UPDATE:

In future Suspense should help. https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a call to the client from a react component the double rendering will happen. For that particular case, I recommend you to use [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)

> The ReactDOMServer object enables you to render components to static
> markup. Typically, it’s used on a Node server:

Or if you did'nt start your project yet you could try using a server-side render framework like [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/)